# postgrey configuration on Fedora Core 21 is very different, and not documented

Tags: postfix, fedora, systemctl, postgrey

In upgrading from Fedora Core 16 to Fedora Core 21, one of the challenges has been getting postfix working with postgrey. I still don't have it working after many long hours focused on it.

In the old strategy, the official directions direct you to author your own script to put into `/etc/init.d`. And, indeed, way back on FC16, I did that! But today, we have `systemctl`. You can install `postgrey` with yum, the repositories know about it. It installs fine. You then enable with `systemctl enable postgrey.service`, and that goes well too.

So far so good. Just a few things left to do...

Next, move over your whitelisting files - seem to be of the same format.

In the old scheme, you'd have a line like this in your postfix main.cf file:

```
...
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_mynetworks,
                               permit_sasl_authenticated,
                               reject_unauth_pipelining,
                               reject_non_fqdn_recipient,
                               reject_unknown_recipient_domain,
                               reject_unauth_destination,
                               check_policy_service inet:127.0.0.1:10023,
                               permit_mynetworks
...
```

In my /etc/init.d, I had written a script of which the following excerpt shows the interesting parts, and it worked well:

```
...
exec="/usr/sbin/postgrey"
prog="postgrey"
options="--unix=/var/spool/postfix/postgrey/socket --inet=10023"

[ -e /etc/sysconfig/$prog ] && . /etc/sysconfig/$prog

lockfile=/var/lock/subsys/$prog

start() {
    [ -x $exec ] || exit 5
    echo -n $"Starting $prog: "
    daemon $exec -d $options
    retval=$?
    echo
    [ $retval -eq 0 ] && touch $lockfile
    return $retval
}
...
```

Notice how the port is specified in `--inet=` and it matches what's in `main.cf`.

But, when I try and use this, the postfix server complains and it won't receive email. It explicitly states it can't connect to postgrey:

```
...
Apr 12 13:27:50 ms1 postfix/smtpd[14273]: warning: connect to 127.0.0.1:10023: Connection refused
Apr 12 13:27:50 ms1 postfix/smtpd[14273]: warning: problem talking to server 127.0.0.1:10023: Connection refused
...
```

I've looked and looked and can't find any configuration information for the new scheme. Asking if postgrey is up and happy gets this:

```
# systemctl status postgrey.service -l
● postgrey.service - Postfix Greylisting Service
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/postgrey.service; enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Sun 2015-04-12 12:13:19 PDT; 1h 19min ago
     Docs: man:postgrey(8)
  Process: 13280 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/postgrey --unix=/var/spool/postfix/postgrey/socket --pidfile=/var/run/postgrey.pid --group=postgrey --user=postgrey --greylist-text=Greylisted for %%s seconds --daemonize $POSTGREY_OPTS (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 13277 ExecStartPre=/bin/rm -f /var/run/postgrey.pid (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 13281 (/usr/sbin/postg)
   CGroup: /system.slice/postgrey.service
           └─13281 /usr/sbin/postgrey --unix=/var/spool/postfix/postgrey/socket --pidfile=/var/run/postgrey.pid --group=postgrey --user=postgrey --greylist-text=Greylisted for %s seconds --daemonize --delay=6

Apr 12 12:13:19 ms1 postgrey[13281]: Process Backgrounded
Apr 12 12:13:19 ms1 postgrey[13281]: 2015/04/12-12:13:19 postgrey (type Net::Server::Multiplex) starting! pid(13281)
Apr 12 12:13:19 ms1 postgrey[13281]: Binding to UNIX socket file "/var/spool/postfix/postgrey/socket"
Apr 12 12:13:19 ms1 postgrey[13281]: Setting gid to "479 479"
Apr 12 12:13:19 ms1 postgrey[13281]: Setting uid to "984"
```

Oddly, it doesn't clearly denote the socket ID - maybe it doesn't have to? But I checked with netstat anyway:

```
# netstat -l | grep postgrey
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     126293   /var/spool/postfix/postgrey/socket
```

...I'm not an expert with `netstat`, but I think this means that the program `/postfix/postgrey/socket` is listening on port 126293.

So, am I supposed to alter my line in main.cf to match this port number? If so, that doesn't work - or, hasn't so far! And, I can't seem to find the place to put an alternate port / socket configuration, so it looks like you're stuck with whatever they gave us.

Any help / advice appreciated. ... I was thinking the only course of action next is to figure out how the `systemctl` toolset works, even though I don't want to take the time now - it's a Sunday!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fedora 21 and RHEL/CentOS 7 use the new Python-based postgrey reimplementation.

In this implementation the *only* change you need in your Postfix configuration is to call the service from `smtpd_recipient_restrictions`. For instance, taken from my own mail server:

```
smtpd_recipient_restrictions =
        #.....other stuff here
        # This should be next-to-last
        check_policy_service unix:postgrey/socket,
        permit
```

Oh, and yes, this was documented in `/usr/share/doc/postgrey-*/README-rpm`. :)

Comment: Thanks, it works! SURE wish someone would update the documentation! Meanwhile, this Q/A will serve as a place others can find an answer until then! BTW, what does the 'permit' restriction do / refer to - I haven't seen that before?

Comment: OH CRAP! I hate it when I miss something so obvious like that! :(  Oh well, live and learn!

Comment: permit just means that if it passes every other check (which all return DUNNO) then the mail will be permitted.

Comment: Oh, OK, well, that's the default - not required! But I guess it's good to be explicit.